# Send SMS via SMTP with UNICODE String vb.net

Tags: vb.net, unicode, smtp

This is my code, i get only ??? chars in message body, 
i tried to use property "mm.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8", i also tried to add a header of "utf-8", never works for me

```
        Dim smtp = New SmtpClient()     
        smtp.EnableSsl =  UseSsl
        smtp.Host =  Host
        smtp.Port =  Port
        smtp.Credentials =  Credentials
        Dim mm = New MailMessage
        mm.From = New MailAddress(Credentials.UserName, ScreenName)
        mm.Subject = Subject
        mm.Body = "אבג"
        mm.IsBodyHtml = True 
        mm.To.AddRange(addresses)  
        smtp.Send(mm)
```

Comment: Um, you are setting the `Body` property to `"???"`, so that is what gets seen on the receiving end. I assume you are setting some *actual* text instead of `"???"`, right? The `BodyEncoding` property is the correct way to specify a charset for the `Body`. Also, you are setting the `IsBodyHtml` property to True, so does your `Body` actually contain HTML or just plain text? If HTML, have you tried including a `<meta>` tag in the HTML so it can specify its own charset?

Comment: Someone edited my code, the right was mm.Body = "אבג"

Comment: What do you mean with "sending SMS via SMTP" are you using an email-SMS gateway? Does the gateway perhaps not properly support unicode in the message body?

Comment: @MGal: `אבג` is not HTML, so do not set `IsBodyHtml` to true. And do set `BodyEncoding`.  If you still have the same problem, then I agree with Sebastian that your SMS gateway might not support Unicode, or at least UTF-8. Try using UTF-16 instead, since SMS carriers historically only support GSM (a form of encoded ASCII) or UCS-2. I would except your SMS gateway to re-encode the text to the necessary encoding for you, but maybe it does not. Another possibility is the SMS receiver gets your Unicode text correctly but simply displays it in a font that does not support those Unicode characters.

Comment: Here is some interesting reading about one person's adventure in trying to use Unicode in SMS: https://www.twilio.com/engineering/2012/11/08/adventures-in-unicode-sms

Comment: Thanks for all, but still need help.  I am try to set mm.IsBodyHtml = False and  mm.BodyEncoding = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode. Does Not work.

Comment: Try `Encoding.Unicode` instead of `Encoding.BigEndianUnicode`.  Nobody uses UTF-16BE for network protocols, but UTF-16LE is not unheard of (though most protocols prefer UTF-8 for Unicode support). If you are STILL having problems, you need to use a packet sniffer or debugging proxy to look at the raw SMTP data you are actually transmitting, make sure it contains the characters you are interested in. If it does, then they are being lost by the SMTP->SMS provider, or even the SMS receiver, so you need to talk to them about it, because the problem would not be on your end.